# Why does Ubuntu use more memory than Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-14.04, jboss6.x

I'm using a JBoss Server, Repertoire Server and Maven build for my Project.

Recently I changed my OS from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu takes more memory than windows for my application.

How can I reduce memory usage in Ubuntu?

Here are some application details for both Windows and Ubuntu:

**Windows - (3 Ear files)**
Jboss                     555Mb
Repertoire Server        281Mb
Eclipse                         268Mb
Browser                       70Mb

**total                            1.146 Gb**

**Ubuntu:(3 Ear files)**
Jboss                           1.1Gb
Repertoire Server        380Mb
Eclipse                         494Mb
Browser                       350Mb

**total                             2.3 Gb**

Comment: What version of windows are you using 10? 7?

Comment: Were the Windows versions 32 bit versions and the Ubuntu ones X64? That could explain a lot.

Comment: I mean it's unlikely to explain much. Ubuntu and Windows are two entirely different OS's there could bea number of reasons why they are different sizes.